# В фоне обновлять функцию

Tags: wordpress

Есть рабочий код, который тянет статью с facebook, разбирает на составляющие и добавляет в БД сайта.

Есть минус этого - то, что он сейчас на frontend висит, и начинает работать, когда я зашел на сайт/обновил - он отработал.

Как сделать можно так, чтобы он на backend работал в "фоне"?

В код заложить время, через которое надо обратится к функции, которая тянет инфу с фб и обрабатывает каждый час.

Сценарий такой: выложил новость на facebook и через час код на WordPress сам чекнул через интервал и добавил новость в БД, если она есть. Сайт, скажем так, заполняется через facebook без дополнительных действий на сайте!

Кто что знает по этому поводу ?

**Обновил**

Код в плагине файла ****-admin.php

```
    add_filter('cron_schedules', 'add_weekly_cron_schedule');
function add_weekly_cron_schedule($schedules)
{
    $schedules['five_min'] = array(
        'interval' => 300
    );
    return $schedules;
}


if (!wp_next_scheduled('my_task_hook')) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), "five_min", 'my_task_hook');
}

// добавляем крон хук
add_action('my_task_hook', 'my_task_function');
function my_task_function()
{
    wp_mail('mypost@mail.com', 'Статья новая', 'Запланированное письмо от WordPress.'); // информирую сам себя что  крон сработал

    $post_data = array(
        'post_title' => 'название статьи',
        'post_content' => 'тело',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_category' => array(0)
    );

    wp_insert_post($post_data);
}
```

На сервере прописал

```
/usr/bin/wget -qO- /home/toys4k00/домен/cbc/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron
```

В wp-config.php дописал

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true);
```

Comment: Серверный крон. Скрипты php (что есть ВП) сами по себе не могут запускаться.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. Как раз нашел функцию wp_cron()

Comment: wp_cron() сработает только в том случае, если есть обращение к сайту. Если обращений нет, то ничего не произойдёт. См. комментарий @SeVlad выше.

Comment: @KAGG Design серверный крон включил уже, указал путь домен/wp-cron.php, в логах на сервере в работе крона нету, но по прежнему не запускает функцию которая написана в плагине. Функция в плагине срабатывает только когда, я в админки. С чем это может быть связанно, в файле конфига  все чисто... даже принудительно включил альтернативный крон define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true);

Comment: Без кода прямо в вопросе - мы не угадаем.

Comment: @KAGG Design добавил код и все что делаю чтоб заработало.

Comment: На вид выглядит всё правильно. Но а) misha, у которого вы позаимствовали код, пишет, что может не работать из-за проблем на сервере б) я уже не помню, почему, но я ушел от wget... У меня на сервере по cron выполняется `php wp-cron.php` - без всяких get-параметров. И всё работает.

Comment: А у вас этот код приведенный выполняется при инициализации плагина? Я вешаю на хук активации плагина. Ну или хотя бы на init.

Comment: И еще - файл назвается ****-admin.php - может, он запускается только в админке?

Comment: @KAGG Design Вчера весь день пытался настроить, чтоб понимать работает или нет крон. Запланированная публикация не публиковалась.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79778/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-pavel8289).

Comment: @KAGG Design - Сори что долго не отвечал.
Крон настроил, дергает сервер его но есть одно "но".
1. Не важно кто зашел на сайт, крон срабатывает. ВП-конфиг прописал на отключение.
2. Можно вообще настроить так чтоб он работал в то время когда сервер дергает файл крон и он сработал ?

Comment: 1. Если в wp-config указано отключить cron, то он не должен срабатывать при заходе на сайт. У меня не срабатывает. 2. Не понял вопрос

Comment: И да - я просто пишу disable_wp_cron, без alternate

Comment: @KAGG Design - Если не помогает, отключение define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true), срабатывает все равно и не важно авторизирован или нет. кэш чистил, запускал на страницах инкогнито и все равно, дергает код. как то это по другому можно исправить ?

Comment: Такого просто не может быть. Я смотрю код `wp-includes/cron.php` и вижу, что если установлено DISABLE_WP_CRON, то ничего не вызывается вообще. Что-то у вас не так. Вставьте в функцию `wp_cron()` распечатку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только сейчас обратил внимание на то, как у вас написана команда wget. Да она просто не работает по локальным файлам!

Надо указывать url:

```
*/5 * * * *    /usr/bin/wget -qO- http://домен-сайта.org/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron  >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Но этого мало. В логах появляется сообщение "cannot execute binary". Почему? Да потому что cron запускается в минимальном environment. Чтобы команда работала в cron, надо запускать так:

```
*/5 * * * *    . $HOME/.bash_profile; /usr/bin/wget -qO- http://домен-сайта.org/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron  >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Вариант проверен, работает. У меня CentOS, в других системах надо заглянуть в домашнюю папку своего пользователя и посмотреть, как называется файл профиля. Может быть, например, `.profile`.

Можно также делать вызов через php напрямую:

```
*/5 * * * *    /usr/bin/php /home/toys4k00/домен/cbc/wp-cron.php
```

Причем php не нуждается в установке профиля. Этот вариант тоже проверен и работает.